# How to fix 'First visit render data isn't accessible, but after second visit it is accessible for rendering' error in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------
**Working Project available at codepen.io: https://codesandbox.io/embed/happy-tharp-slvf5** 
---------------------------------------------------------------------

The problem: When I type in Home and I click the button, it retrieves all data from the API of the government. And JS pushes the link in the history so I get redirected to the car detail page. This first time I come to this page my content isn't loaded on the page (even though I can console log the data), but when I visit the page again (without reloading) it works without any errors.

Does anyone know how to deal with this solution?

These recordings show my problem; 

**WORKFLOW:**
https://youtu.be/H8YoIkQ2MHk

**CONSOLE:**
https://youtu.be/KtVujQuH8ec

Anyone any idea what the problem actually is?

(Disclaimer: Please make sure you watch them both, I am not a native English speaker may be the problem I described can have misconceptions. The videos are great e.g. body (mouse/keyboard) language)

- I tried at compononentDidMound to add it to the state of the car.js component and call the data in that layout with that reference.
  I got one smell: Maybe it could be the async that it loads to fast so I need to use some middleware like redux-thunk to prevent this?

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Car extends Component {
  state = {
    id: null
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    let id = this.props.match.params.car_id;
    this.setState({
      id: id
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log("CAR:");
    console.log(this.props.car);
    console.log("CAR.VOERTUIG:");
    console.log(this.props.car.voertuig);
    const voertuig = this.props.car.voertuig;

    const voertuigList = voertuig.length ? (
      voertuig.map(car => {
        return (
          <div className="car card" key={car.kenteken}>
            <div className="card-content">
              <span className="card-title">{car.handelsbenaming}</span>

              <ul className="collection">
                <li className="collection-item">
                  Datum tenaamstelling: {car.datum_tenaamstelling}
                </li>
                <li className="collection-item">
                  Vervaldatum APK: {car.vervaldatum_apk}
                </li>
                <li className="collection-item">Kleur: {car.eerste_kleur}</li>
                <li className="collection-item">Lengte: {car.lengte}</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })
    ) : (
      <div className="center">No car with such licenseplate found!</div>
    );

    const terugroepActie = this.props.car.terugroepActie;
    const terugroepActieList = terugroepActie.length ? (
      terugroepActie.map(actie => {
        return (
          <div className="car card" key={actie.referentiecode_rdw}>
            <div className="card-content">
              <span className="card-title">
                Terugroep actie: {actie.categorie_defect}
              </span>

              <ul className="collection">
                <li className="collection-item">
                  Omschrijving: {actie.omschrijving_defect}
                </li>
                <li className="collection-item">
                  Herstel: {actie.beschrijving_van_het_herstel}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })
    ) : (
      <div className="center">Geen terugroep acties :)!</div>
    );

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h4>{this.state.id}</h4>
        {voertuigList}
        {terugroepActieList}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  let id = ownProps.match.params.car_id;
  return {
    car: state.cars.find(car => car.kenteken === id)
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Car);
```

I expected the same outcome from the second visit also in the first visit. But it didn't.
I hope it is some little thing that I forgot (like a typo). :D

*EDIT: Maybe handy to know in the 'Console video' if you notice you see Array(0) for voertuigen (vehicles in Dutch) but if I expand the array I see clearly the data.
Also after the second visit to the page in the 'Console video', it changes to Array(1) and displays the same data.*

Answer (score 0):

As state changes,component rerender( you can receive new props in componentWillReceivePorps ) so mapStateToProps will not call again,that's why you are not getting data for first time,second time all cars data is already stored.
Please check below code and let me know:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Car extends Component {
  state = {
    id: null
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    let id = this.props.match.params.car_id;
    this.setState({
      id: id
    });
  }

  render() {

    const car = this.props.cars.find(car => car.kenteken === this.props.match.params.car_id);
    const voertuig = car.voertuig;
    console.log("CAR:");
    console.log(car);
    console.log("CAR.VOERTUIG:");
    console.log(car.voertuig);



    const voertuigList = voertuig.length ? (
      voertuig.map(car => {
        return (
          <div className="car card" key={car.kenteken}>
            <div className="card-content">
              <span className="card-title">{car.handelsbenaming}</span>

              <ul className="collection">
                <li className="collection-item">
                  Datum tenaamstelling: {car.datum_tenaamstelling}
                </li>
                <li className="collection-item">
                  Vervaldatum APK: {car.vervaldatum_apk}
                </li>
                <li className="collection-item">Kleur: {car.eerste_kleur}</li>
                <li className="collection-item">Lengte: {car.lengte}</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })
    ) : (
        <div className="center">No car with such licenseplate found!</div>
      );

    const terugroepActie = this.props.car.terugroepActie;
    const terugroepActieList = terugroepActie.length ? (
      terugroepActie.map(actie => {
        return (
          <div className="car card" key={actie.referentiecode_rdw}>
            <div className="card-content">
              <span className="card-title">
                Terugroep actie: {actie.categorie_defect}
              </span>

              <ul className="collection">
                <li className="collection-item">
                  Omschrijving: {actie.omschrijving_defect}
                </li>
                <li className="collection-item">
                  Herstel: {actie.beschrijving_van_het_herstel}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })
    ) : (
        <div className="center">Geen terugroep acties :)!</div>
      );

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h4>{this.state.id}</h4>
        {voertuigList}
        {terugroepActieList}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    cars: state.cars
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Car);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response brother!
This didn't work out eventually the error I had is still preserved within this code.
Source:
<https://prnt.sc/ow3i1w>
Unfortunately and thanks for your time!

Comment: @TarikHacialiogullari It would be good if you create https://pastebin.com/ or https://codesandbox.io/ so that I can check the error

Comment: Sure, brother! Here you go: [https://codesandbox.io/embed/happy-tharp-slvf5](https://codesandbox.io/embed/happy-tharp-slvf5)

Comment: Any Idea yet, about the solution?